# How can I ungroup applications separately in unity launcher?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

Unity is pretty cool. One of main feature I like with Unity is access running apps with handy <kbd>Win</kbd>key.  However one issue is annoying me with grouping of apps without tray feature.

I'm running more than 2 wine apps [wine-app1, wine-app2, wine-app3]. All of them appears in Unity application placer under one icon. Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>key (hold it for 1 sec) shows up the number and pressing corresponding number takes to a particular application. This is the difference with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. In ALT+TAB you walk through all application windows and select the one you wanted.

However, you walk through rest as well which you don't need. In my working environment, I use few editors and few windows apps due to company IT. Since all windows apps are grouped as one, everytime when i wanted to access wine-app1, wine-app2, the wine-app3 appears in walk through. [this is something similar to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> - Show all windows in a tiles fashion] I access wine-app1 & 2 frequently and very very occasionally use the wine-app3. But, it should be running in the background so that I can access when its needed.

What i'm looking for a way to pin the apps with a number. So that, I can access quickly. If I want to access wine-app1 and wine-app2, I had to pass wine-app3 and minimize wine-app3 everytime (since it appears using win key) I access other two apps using <kbd>Win</kbd>key. Is there way, we can let unity to treat these apps separate one though these are wine based apps. It shouldn't even group. And I can give new icons and access in separate.

Comment: Can you edit your question explain what keyboard shortcut you're using to cycle through the applications? That part is unclear to me. Like, are you cycling through them or something?

Comment: I'm sorry about being unclear sometimes. Let me add more explanation to the question.

Comment: you do know that you can click the application icon to switch quickly between windows?

Comment: @nerdy_kid:unity is too good because it helps to stay away from mouse.

Comment: have you already tried pressing Win-W? Does that suit your workflow?

Comment: Is it possible to ungroup the google chrome applications, created using standart google chrome menu (Click the wrench icon  on the browser toolbar.
Select Tools.
Select Create application shortcuts.)? Because it is very uncomfortable, i start calendar (maked with google apps) and it's grouping with my chrome browser

Comment: Finally in ubuntu 13.04, I got what I wanted. Right click on unity icon and choose which application you want to go to, instead of cycling through all apps until you find what you want.

Answer (score 4):

The way links show up and act in Unity (or most modern Linux-desktops for that matter) is directed by the .desktop files (under: /usr/share/applications/ or for a single user under ~/.local/share/applications/) For more on that see: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/. Another good guide on using the .desktop file to change the behaviour  is http://themagicofscience.blogspot.com/2011/05/unity-adding-items-to-dock.html (inclidung further references)

As standard setting, wine creates e.g. for Picasa (in my case in a file "~/.local/share/applications/wine-Programme-Picasa 3-Picasa 3.desktop") the command

`Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/[user]/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/aj/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Startmenü/Program Files/Picasa\\ 3/Picasa\\ 3.lnk`

that has as a result that all wine-apps appear under a single icon in the launcher.  To change this behaviour you have to create a new .desktop file for picasa or change the existing one so that wine directly launches the application's executable.

so the command should be (don't ask me, why ~ or %USERNAME% don't work here)

`Exec=wine "/home/[user]/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Google/Picasa3/Picasa3.exe"`

To create the link and the accompaning icons I followed the rather complicated guide 
under the bug report "Unable to add Wine applications to Unity launcher"

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/704187/comments/3
whole report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/704187/

But with the aforementionedguides you might even create the .desktop file yourself or at least adapt it to your needs once you have the correct basic setting.

Added benefit for this is that you see the application icon in the launcher (not just wine) AND can pin the wine app to the launcher.

HTH
Andreas